# Can't connect to ParamStore from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I try to get a value from AWS ParamStore using this code:

```
AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient client = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient();
var param = client.GetParameter(new GetParameterRequest { Name = "foo", WithDecryption = true });
```

I get this exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: A WebException with status ConnectFailure was thrown. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 52.94.225.93:443
```

Is `52.94.225.93` an AWS server for the ParamStore? I assume the SDK is trying to connect to the ParamStore but fails because maybe the EC2 machine's Security Group doesn't allow it.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: https://whoisip.ovh/52.94.225 states that that IP currently belongs to AWS. Could you try opening the outgoing port for 52.94.225.93 and seeing if this resolves it??

Comment: OK, seems like our AWS environment is setup in a such a way that we need to go through an environment-specific proxy. I'll have to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the error by configuring the proxy server (a VPC egress proxy if I understood it correctly).

The proxy host and port were already available as environment variables somehow.

```
var proxyHost = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProxyServer");
var proxyPort = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProxyPort");
var config = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementConfig
{
    ProxyHost = proxyHost,
    ProxyPort = Int32.Parse(proxyPort)
};
var client = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(config);
```